# combine views date exposed filters

Tags: views

i want to combine the two drop downs that the views date exposed filter creates.

ie. [year][month]

i want to know if this can be made into one drop down like [year,month].

Is this possible?

Comment: no logic in your question

Comment: @Bala i just want to know if its possible. Im building a site and this is the way it was designed out. One jump menu to filter by month & year, not two jumps separating the two individually.

Comment: not possible, you can not show both year and month in one list.

Comment: Certainly possible, just not easy and might require hacking Views. Anyway, if I have +- 2 months input, it makes no sense to make it 2 fields, not even at the beginning or end of the year when year matters.

Comment: that was my thoughts. this is a drop down for an event page so it will only list the events that are upcoming.